# Prolog List. Check if first and last element in list is similar

Tags: list, prolog, dcg

Example:

```
firstlast([1,2,3,4,1]).
true;

firstlast([1,2,3,4]).
false;

firstlast([5,10,4,3]).
false;

exc...
```

The problem is im only allowed to use recursion with the predicate "firstlast". ?
I have really tried to break this, but i cant seem to check / compare the last element with the first.

Any hints ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**UPDATE :** Since you are not allowed to use other predicates, try this:

```
firstlast([H,H]).
firstlast([F,_|T]) :- firstlast([F|T]).
```

The first predicate deals with the base case, the second one removes the second element in a list of three or more items, and recurses down.

Comment: `Xs = [f,Xs], firstlast(Xs).` succeeds. Is this intended?

Comment: @false I just tried this in SWI, and I got `false` back, Am I missing something? (note: I edited my answer, there was a typo in the first line - it said `last(X,list)` instead of `last(X,List)`)

Comment: `first(H, H).` must be removed.

Answer (score 2):

You probably mean that the first and last element are the same. Here is a solution using [dcg](/questions/tagged/dcg)-notation:

```
firstlast(Xs) :-
    phrase(([X],...,[X]), Xs).

... --> [] | [_], ... .
```

I am not sure whether `firstlast([1])` should succeed or not ...

Answer (score 0):

Well since you can only use a recursion with firstlast/1 the solution will look like:

```
firstlast(...) :- ... .
firstlast(...) :- ... .
firstlast(...) :- ... .
....
firstlast(...) :- ... .
```

some of those will be the rules regarding the base case and some of them the rules that "eat away" the problem.
this problem requires one check: compare the first and the last element. so, in your base case you should have only these 2 elements; you dont need anything else. so the solution will ignore all the other elements

last hint: you can access the 2 first elements of a list with the following unification pattern:

```
foo([H1,H2|T])
```

Answer (score 0):

So fair i got this:

```
firstlast([H,_|T]) :-
(T1 = H, T1 = T) -> firstlast([H|T]).
```

My code compares the last and first element but the recursion is just wrong :/

As answered above it should not be allowed to succed with one element in the list.
Though im only allowed to use the predicate "firstlast".

Comment: This code would be far more visible if you added it to the question itself, rather than posting it as an answer. You can always edit your question by clicking the `edit` link.